# MediaCodec video encoding from byteBuffer fails

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to encode the OpenGL output of my program to an mp4 file (Android 4.4, Huawei P6, using the MediaCodec and MediaMuxer). Since my app's lifecycle is pretty closely tied to a GLSurfaceView, I don't want to risk braking this fragile part of my app by replacing that with a custom surface that's encodable directly, so I initially wanted to do something less intrusive, like just copying the pixels over to main memory and encoding from a byteBuffer. I could not find any complete examples of this, so I used the Grafika code (https://github.com/google/grafika) as a starting point.

It seems to work OK, and at one point it did produce a working MP4 file, but it's borked in its current state and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Encoding/muxing seems to work fine, until I actually close the Encoder, at which point I get the following error in the logcat:

```
07-06 20:17:24.890: A/ACodec(24650): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:3162 CHECK_EQ( (int)info->mStatus,(int)BufferInfo::OWNED_BY_COMPONENT) failed: 0 vs. 1
07-06 20:17:24.890: A/libc(24650): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000604a (code=-6), thread 24795 (CodecLooper)
```

And my app closes

Can anyone tell me what this error actually means? It looks like I'm either holding on the a buffer (input or output?) that I should not hold on to, or have released a buffer prematurely that I should have held on to? And which buffer is it, in or out or the info buffer? I'm very confused...

For reference, here's the code I'm using to encode:

```
package bla;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoEncoder 
{
    public static final boolean debugLog = true;
    private static final String TAG = "bla";

    private MediaCodec m_MediaEncoder = null;
    private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    private MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo;
    private int mTrackIndex;
    private boolean mMuxerStarted;

    private int m_encodeWidth;
    private int m_encodeHeight;
    private int m_frameRate = 30;
    private int m_frameInterval = 5;
    private String m_fileName;

    private int m_numRecordedFrames=0;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public boolean Start( String filename, int width, int height, float fps )
    {
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 )
        {
            m_encodeWidth = width;
            m_encodeHeight = height;
            m_fileName = new String( filename );    // make a copy

            if( debugLog ) Log.i(TAG, String.format("Bitrate for encoder set to %d", bitrate));

            m_MediaEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
            MediaFormat mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", m_encodeWidth, m_encodeHeight );
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);
//          mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, m_frameRate);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_Format32bitBGRA8888);
//          mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, m_frameInterval);
            mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
            m_MediaEncoder.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            m_MediaEncoder.start();

            mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

            mTrackIndex = -1;
            mMuxerStarted = false;

            try 
            {   // delete the video file if it already exists
                FileOutputStream videoOutputFileStream = new FileOutputStream( m_fileName );
                videoOutputFileStream.close();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"File not found when creating movie file");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"I/O exception creating movie file");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }


            // create the muxer object
            try 
            {   // delete the video file if it already exists
                mMuxer = new MediaMuxer( m_fileName, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"I/O exception creating muxer");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Started Movie Encoder");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public void Stop()
    {
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 )
        {
            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Stopping Movie Encoder");

            if( m_MediaEncoder != null )
            {
//              if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Flush()");
//              m_MediaEncoder.flush();
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Stop()");
                m_MediaEncoder.stop();
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Release()");
                m_MediaEncoder.release();
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"set null");
                m_MediaEncoder = null;

                Log.i(TAG,"Stopping Muxer");
                if( m_numRecordedFrames > 0 )
                {
                    if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Stop()");
                    mMuxer.stop();
                    if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Release()");
                    mMuxer.release();
                }
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"set null");
                mMuxer = null;
            }

        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public void EncodeCurrentFrameBuffer()
    {
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 )
        {
            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Saving movie frame START");

            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"About to request input buffer");
            ByteBuffer[] videoInputBuffers = m_MediaEncoder.getInputBuffers();
            int inputBufferIndex = m_MediaEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10);
            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Got input buffer: " + Integer.toString(inputBufferIndex) );

            if(inputBufferIndex >= 0) 
            {
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,String.format("Encoding frame of %d x %d", m_encodeWidth, m_encodeHeight ));

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = videoInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                inputBuffer.clear();
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Reading pixels from OpenGL");
                GLES20.glReadPixels( 0, 0, m_encodeWidth, m_encodeHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, inputBuffer );

                long totaltime = (long)(m_numRecordedFrames+1) * 1000000 / (long)m_frameRate;

                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Sending input buffer to encoder");
                m_MediaEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, m_encodeWidth * m_encodeHeight * 4, totaltime, 0);

                drainEncoder();
            }
            else
            {
                videoInputBuffers = null;
            }

            if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"Saving movie frame END");

            m_numRecordedFrames++;
        }       
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public void drainEncoder() 
    {
        final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10;

        ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = m_MediaEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
        while (true) 
        {
            int encoderStatus = m_MediaEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER)
            {
                // no output available yet
                if (debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "no output available (yet), break out of while");
                {
                    break;      // out of while
                } 
            } 
            else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) 
            {
                // not expected for an encoder
                encoderOutputBuffers = m_MediaEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
            } 
            else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) 
            {
                // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
                if (mMuxerStarted) 
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");
                }
                MediaFormat newFormat = m_MediaEncoder.getOutputFormat();
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);

                // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
                mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                mMuxer.start();
                mMuxerStarted = true;
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "muxer started");
            } 
            else if (encoderStatus < 0) 
            {
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                // let's ignore it
            } 
            else 
            {
                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG,"EncoderStatus = " + Integer.toString(encoderStatus));
                ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                if (encodedData == null) 
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                }

                if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) 
                {
                    // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                    // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                    if (debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
                    mBufferInfo.size = 0;
                }

                if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) 
                {
                    if (!mMuxerStarted) 
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started");
                    }

                    // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                    encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);

                    if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "writing sample data to muxer");

                    mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);

                    if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "sent " + mBufferInfo.size + " bytes to muxer, ts=" + mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
                }

                if( debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "releasing output buffer");
                m_MediaEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

                if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) 
                {
                    if (debugLog) Log.i(TAG, "end of stream reached");
                    break;      // out of while
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Kind regards,
Nils Desle

Comment: That's an assertion failure in the stagefright library (the native code that interfaces with mediaserver).  It's getting into a weird state; this is a bug in the platform.  It should be possible to work around it.  For this sort of thing you generally need to find some code that works and gradually morph it into code that fails, then back off a step.  Having said all that, it might be easier (and faster) to render twice the way Android Breakout does (also based on GLSurfaceView -- http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#BreakoutPatch).

Comment: Dang. I was hoping for something easier :)  I'll give the breakout patch a go then! Thanks!

Comment: @fadden: I'm new to git. I've cloned the android breakout repo, but is there an automatic way to apply the patch you supply in the link above? Thanks!

Comment: Use `git am` (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html).  The real value of having it as a patch is that it shows the set of changes required to add GL recording to a game based around GLSurfaceView.